# Can't get headers after they are sent (windows only?)

Tags: node.js, express

I'm aware this question has already been asked a lot already, however I've spent the day reading about this and I'm still stuck. I have the following function which goes away and does a get on a local server.

```
    var http = require('http');
    var config = require('../config.js');

    exports.get_test_jobs = function(res, data) {

      var optionsget = {
        host: config.jobs_rest_host,
        port: config.jobs_rest_port,
        path: "/jobs3/jobtest",
        method: "GET"
      };

      var reqGet = http.request(optionsget, function(res) {
        res.setEncoding('utf-8');

        res.on('data', function(d) {
          return data.send(d);
        });

      });

      reqGet.end();
      reqGet.on('error', function(e) {
        console.error(e);
      });
    }

/* a few more functions along the same idea */
```

This is being called from my server.js file

```
app.get('/jobs/test', jobs_hdlr.get_test_jobs);
```

Here is the weird bit - this seems to work fine when I run this on unix (mac and ubuntu) this works fine, but when I try to run it on my windows (work) pc I get the dreaded "Can't get headers after they are sent" error. Could this be a windows thing? Or am I just being lucky with my other machines?

I'm using express 3.12 - could it be to do with that? (I think express 4.4 is now out ... I should probably upgrade, but lots of stuff has been removed)

(Just to be clear, for now I'm always running the rest server from the same machine, phase 2 will be to host that somewhere else)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'data' events can be emitted more than once (which is most likely what is happening in your case). Never assume it will be emitted only once.

Comment: Yes, you're spot on, changing the code so it didn't rely on data only being there once seems to have worked - thank you!

Comment: Also, you should simply be able to just do `res.pipe(data);` instead of manually sending back data individual chunks or buffering and sending a single chunk.